# How to sync music in a rhythm game like magic tile3

Tags: python, midi

I am trying to build  a clone of magic tile3 ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LEvffYhQlaE )
I tried with librosa to get the beat with the same song in python, save the output in CSV file and use it in flutter but it was not synced to the music ( nothing like the game).
you can see my code bellow

```py
import librosa.display

y, sr = librosa.load('romance.mp3',)

tempo, beats = librosa.beat.beat_track(y=y, sr=sr)

beat_times =  librosa.frames_to_time(beats,sr=sr)
librosa.output.times_csv("romance.csv",beat_times)
```

My question is what can I use to sync the game with the music.
Thank you

Comment: Show us what you tried so we can point you the way

Comment: @DavidBaak, I just add the code in the question. Thank